# Conditional substitution in VIM

Tags: substitute

Is there a way to set Negate in the substitution command? In other words how to substitute any character except `|` to `-` and all `|` to `+`. Example:

```
| some text | other text |
```

to

```
+-----------+------------+
```

Is there a shortest way than `:s/[^|]/-/g | s/|/+/g` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the replace special substitution:

```
:s/./\= submatch(0) == '|' ? '+' : '-'/g
```

Here `\=` says to use the following expression to use as the result string.

And it's checking for `submatch(0)` (the char matched by the `/./` pattern) and do a condition on that.

Have a look at:

- `:h sub-replace-special`
- `:h submatch()`

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you can use the system's `tr` program:

```
:.!tr '| -z' '+-'
```